# Wait for a functions to finish in sequence Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have three functions prints 20,30,10 as per setTimeout how should i make them print 10,20,30 order using promise
How to write these callbacks to print right order.

P.S. : This is not a duplicate question. Thanks !

```js
var A = function(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(10)
        callback();
    }, 2000);
};

var B = function(callback) {
    console.log(20);
    callback();
};

var C = function(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(30)
        callback();
    }, 200);
};

function runTask() {
  var wait = ms => new Promise ((resolve,reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
  var FuncA = wait();
  FuncA.then(() => A(function () {}))
   . then(() => B(function () {}))
    .then(() => C(function () {}));
}

runTask();
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure I understood your question.  But, here it is based on what I understood.  You weren't doing anything with the callback so I didn't pass them.
In your code function B didn't have a delay.

```js
function delayAsync(ms) {
    return new Promise(p_resolve => setTimeout(p_resolve, ms));
}

async function A(callback) {
    await delayAsync(2000);
    console.log(10);
    if (callback instanceof Function) {
        callback();
    }
}

async function B(callback) {
    console.log(20);
    if (callback instanceof Function) {
        callback();
    }
}

async function C(callback) {
    await delayAsync(200);
    console.log(30);
    if (callback instanceof Function) {
        callback();
    }
}

function runTask() {

    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await A();
        await B();
        await C();
        resolve();
    });
}

runTask().then(() => console.log('done'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with Promises, you could create a helper function that performs a `setTimeout` but returns a `Promise`. This will preserve the order of console logs:

```js
const setTimeoutAsync = (fn, ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(fn()), ms));

var A = function(callback) {
    return setTimeoutAsync(() => {
        console.log(10)
        callback();
    }, 2000);
};

var B = function(callback) {
    console.log(20)
    callback();
};

var C = function(callback) {
    return setTimeoutAsync(() => {
        console.log(30)
        callback();
    }, 200);
};

function runTask() { // refactored since A now returns a Promise
    return A(() => {})
        .then(() => B(() => {}))
        .then(() => C(() => {}));
}

runTask();
```

Alternatively, if you'd like a clean solution and don't mind adding a third party module, you could use [`async-af`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-af), a library for chainable asynchronous JavaScript methods that I maintain:

```js
const setTimeoutAsync = (fn, ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(fn()), ms));

var A = function(callback) {
    return setTimeoutAsync(() => {
        console.log(10)
        callback();
    }, 2000);
};

var B = function(callback) {
    console.log(20)
    callback();
};

var C = function(callback) {
    return setTimeoutAsync(() => {
        console.log(30)
        callback();
    }, 200);
};

// to run in parallel you would omit `series`, but
// since you want to run the tasks in order include it:
function runTask(...tasks) {
      return AsyncAF(tasks).series.forEach(task => task(() => {}));
}

runTask(A, B, C);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/async-af@7.0.11/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks Scott for providing different approaches !
I am curious, how will you do it without changing A, B, C functions. ?